# Give us an option to disable activity notification bar

Tags: feature-request, notifications

On Meta, I've been noticing over the past several weeks that there is a notification bar that appears (and the site's favicon "glows" on its browser tab) whenever new activity happens on the site. Before this feature is implemented on the rest of the SE sites, would it be possible to implement a user preference to disable it or at least adjust the minimum frequency at which it appears?

While this would be a nice feature on some of the not so busy sites, on busy sites as Meta, I find it most annoying to have this showing up every minute or so. If I want to see new activity, I'll hit Refresh when I'm ready to see it.

**Update**
Now that more sites are starting to glow the favicon whenever the "x questions have new activity" banner is shown (I noticed that Super User is now doing that), I'd really like a way to turn that feature off or at least specify an update frequency so I don't have to be bothered by it so often.

Comment: If you're talking about the grey "*x* questions with new activity" bar, this feature has existed for a *long* time.

Comment: I didn't really notice it until a few weeks ago, and since it only exists on Meta, I had figured that it was a new feature being tested. I'd still like a user preference to allow me to turn it off or at least turn down the annoyance factor.